# Using a spring constraint in Godot

Tags: 3d, godot

Can anyone tell me how springs can be used in the Godot graphic program? I know can in 2 dimensions mode. I have looked everywhere, including video sites, but cannot find anything?

Comment: What kind of springs are you talking about? The built-in SpringArm node? Something to do with physics? What do you mean by you can in 2D?

Comment: 2D has a spring function available, but there appears to be nothing for 3D. If I did a car as provided by Godot functions there is suspension provided which would be something like springs.